# Cast IEnumerable<PageData> to Episerver PageDataCollection

Tags: linq, ienumerable, episerver

How could i get a Linq Query back to Episerver PageDataCollection? I cant find anything about it on the net.

```
//This becomes IEnumerable<DataPapge> i need it to be PageDataCollection
var  banners = DataFactory.Instance
                          .GetChildren(CurrentPageLink)
                          .Where(child => child.PageTypeName == "SomeName") ;

//BannerCollection becomse null 
PageDataCollection bannerCollection = banners as PageDataCollection;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the constructor with an `ICollection<PageData>`:

```
PageDataCollection bannerCollection = new PageDataCollection(banners.ToList());
```

( found in the [source](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms5/html/T_EPiServer_Core_PageDataCollection.htm) )

Or even better the other constructor taking an `IEnumerable`:

```
PageDataCollection bannerCollection = new PageDataCollection(banners);
```